# Fabric js image optimize

Tags: compression, fabricjs

I am using fabric js and using a upload image option on that, But here people upload image which is big in size ( 2mb etc), So is there a way to compress this,

I am saving whole canvas in JSON format in database and then retrieve but due to the image size the size of canvas also increases

Here is the fiddle

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/jaibuu/Vp6wa/`
```

Answer (score 0):

Here in your js fiddle code you should pass the Path reference of the image.

```
 var image = new fabric.Image(imgObj);
        image.set({
            left: 250,
            top: 250,
            angle: 20,
            padding: 10,
            cornersize: 10
        });
```

instead of saving serialized image to canvas , only path reference will be stored in jsonObj.

```
 var image = new fabric.Image(imgObj);
        image.set({
            left: 250,
            top: 250,
            angle: 20,
            padding: 10,
            cornersize: 10,
            sourcePath: url
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you are converting canvas to json format and there is no option available for json optimization. but if you use [canvas.toDataURL](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#toDataURL) method, there is a **quality** option available for this method, if u want to decrease the size of converted image, u set the **quality to 0.0** and it will generate a low quality and low size image.

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
  format: 'jpeg',
  quality: 0.8
});
```

**Note: Keep in mind that format must be jpeg if u use quality option.**